# I want to create a collection of objects from a larger collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have an object "elements" which is a collection of HTML form elements.
It consists of address1 address2 city state zip email confirm email etcetera

I want create a new object that is a subset of the larger original object.
Which will consist of just address2 city state month day and year

I need this to be reusable so I do not want to redeclare them individually every time.

I have tried various ways but have been able to create this subset and apply a jQuery method to it.

I try to create an object, then namespace the elements into it but then  get a "object has no method" error.

Here is one example of what I am trying to do

```
var flds = [];
    flds.A2 = el.address2;
    flds.CI = el.city;
    flds.ST = el.state;
    flds.MN = el.month;
    flds.DY = el.day;
    flds.YR = el.year;

flds.css('display','none');
```

Here is what the object looks like in Chrome dev tools:

```
[A2: e.fn.e.init[1], CI: e.fn.e.init[1], ST: e.fn.e.init[1], MN: e.fn.e.init[1], DY: e.fn.e.init[1]…]
```

How do I get the collection to be accessible to the jQuery .css property and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have said you have an array of HTML elements, which are not a jQuery selectors. HTML elements do not have the method `css`. You will have to select the elements with jQuery then call `css`

```
 $(flds).css('display','none');
```